# Providing a default string parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I've always used the following syntax to ensure that the input variable isn't *null*.

```
function f(input){
  if(input === null)
    input = "";
  ...
}
```

Lately, I noticed that it's shorter to express it as follows.

```
function f(input){
  input = input ? input : "";
  ...
}
```

But also, I've seen this syntax.

```
function f(input){
  input = input || "";
  ...
}
```

1. Are those equivalent (not in **what** they do but in **how** they do it)?
2. Which is most recommended (readability etc.)?

Note that I'll be strictly working with inputs of strings such that it's either valid one or null (not provided at all). If I'd like to extend the protection to include other types, what additional issues should I take into consideration?

Comment: Another one - `input || (input = "");`

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk Would it be faster? Also - I'd expect *return* or *input = * in front of your suggestion. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I do not think that this is the code you have to optimise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that they aren't all the same. #2 and #3 have precisely the same result: unless `input` is truthy, set it to an empty string. #1 means says "unless `input` is `null`, set it to an empty string. So if `false` was provided, `input` would be `false` in #1 but `''` in #2 and #3.

If nothing was provided to #1, (i.e. `f()`, `input` would be `undefined`, because that is the value that is passed when a parameter is missing, not `null`. One of these would fix this:

```
if(input === undefined)
if(input == null)
```

Otherwise, yes, they are functionally equivalent. For me, the best way to write it would be

```
input = input || "";
```

That is my preferred style. It may be yours; it may not. But, above all, ***be consistent***.

Comment: Also, since the OP was worried about speed in his comments, your preferred style is [faster](http://jsperf.com/check-false-value)

Comment: @Nile Though the difference is what might optimistically be called "infinitesimal".